# App store connect (erroneously?) does not prompt me for encryption exempt documents

Tags: encryption, app-store-connect, development

I have a LOB app that allows users to encrypt files with a specified password. Hashing is used to derive a fixed length-key which is then used by AES to encrypt the content.
(It also uses HTTPS and the native keychain, but both of these are exempt anyway).

From what I understand, this is actually not an exempt from the [US export regulation](https://US%20export%20regulation) since I use encryption, but not for the sake of any of the points specified in f ("support of entertainment, mass commercial broadcasts or medical records management").

However, if I take the questionnaire provided by App Store Connect, it actually just prompts me with I reminder that I am required to file a report to the US Gov if I use HTTPS, and not  the usual file upload I would expect.

I figured that what triggers this outcome is this question:

> Does your app implement any encryption algorithms that are proprietary
> or not accepted as standards by international standard bodies (IEEE,
> IETF, ITU, etc.)?

I chose 'No', since AES is specified by the IETF. The upload prompt only appears when I choose 'Yes' here.
I really don't understand how using standardized algorithm should free me from filing a report, and apple's documentation only makes this infinitely more confusing.

My conclusions would be:

I just leave `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` on 'No' (which apple suggests but seems wrong to me).
I file a report to the US Gov anyway as Apple is out of line here.

Q: Are my assumptions right? An if so: If the described procedure does not require `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` as YES, what even does?